# 400 bad request UnityWebRequest

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking

hey everyone any ideas why im getting a 400 error? im trying to post a json to a subscription list. doing that through postman works just fine!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class testing : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public InputField field;
    [SerializeField]
    private Email _email = new Email();
    private string URL = "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/YeXzKp/members?api_key=pk_ec448e1bdab7504c143466ca5eeabc5e95&profiles=[]";
    IEnumerator SaveIntoJson()
    {
        string data = JsonUtility.ToJson(_email);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "Data.json", data);

        //UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("URL", data);
        //www.SetRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put(URL, data);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        //yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
        Debug.Log(data);
    }


    public void SaveData()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SaveIntoJson());
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Email
{
    public List<Profiles> profiles = new List<Profiles>();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Profiles
{
    public string email; 
}
```

Comment: Is `data` what you expect it to be?

Comment: yeah i used debug log on request,handlertext and found out that No JSON object could be decoded . so i decoded it and now works!

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class testing : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public InputField field;
    [SerializeField]
    private Email _email = new Email();
    private string URL = "urlHere&profiles=[]";

    public void SaveData()
    {
        string data = JsonUtility.ToJson(_email);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "Data.json", data);
        StartCoroutine(SaveIntoJson(URL , data));
    }
    IEnumerator SaveIntoJson(string url, string data)
    {
        var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(jsonBytes);

        request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
            Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
        Debug.Log(data);
    }

}
[System.Serializable]
public class Email
{
    public List<Profiles> profiles = new List<Profiles>();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Profiles
{
    public string email; 
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it included some simple text explaining what you changed to fix the problem, and how that works.